# how to find address from lat long in android

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

Please Help me in finding address from given lat long  in android.

As I have put the lat long values from gps service I need to find the user location where the user is standing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to perform Reverse Geocoding for this. See: [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding
Make a call to one of these services.

Google provide one for Javascript, maybe they also have a API you could use?
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#ReverseGeocoding